# Lowering the start indexes in sums

Tags: summation, computational-complexity

I'm implementing a CYK algorithm in my software and I've found a pseudo-code on Wikipedia. Here's its complexity(modified version for special use, which doesn't go from `j=1` to `n-i+1`):

[image]

However, pseudo-codes are usually indexing from `1`, but in programming everything starts at `0`. My goal is to make this algorithm go from `i = 1`, `j = 0` and `k = 0` and getting exactly the same sum. I kind of forgot how to do this properly and been lost in this problem for a while.

If possible, I'd like **not** to have **anything outside** of these sums. The goal is not to compute these sums, just to **lower their indexes**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a sum 
$$
\sum_{k=a}^b c_k,
$$
you can make a change of index, for example, $k'=k-d$, and you get
$$
\sum_{k'=a-d}^{b-d} c_{k'+d},
$$
for some $d$. You may check that this holds, for example, if $a=2$ and $b=5$: both sums are $c_2+c_3+c_4+c_5$.

Because the indices $k$ and $k'$ are just dummy summation indices (they don't have a meaning outside the sum), we can of course call $k'$ in the final expression just $k$:
$$
\sum_{k=a}^b c_k = \sum_{k'=a-d}^{b-d} c_{k'+d} = \sum_{k=a-d}^{b-d} c_{k+d}
$$

---

Let's work through your formula,
$$
\sum_{i=2}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^{i-1} 1\right) \right).
$$
Introducing $i'=i-1$, we get (note that we have an $i$ inside the sum so that should change as well)
$$
\sum_{i'=1}^{n-1} \left(\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^{i'} 1\right) \right).
$$
Introducing $j'=j-1$, we get (note that we don't have a $j$ inside the sum over $j$ so nothing changes there)
$$
\sum_{i'=1}^{n-1} \left(\sum_{j'=0}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{i'} 1\right) \right),
$$
and finally, with $k'=k-1$, we get
$$
\sum_{i'=1}^{n-1} \left(\sum_{j'=0}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{k'=0}^{i'-1} 1\right) \right).
$$
Finally, if we don't like those $'$s, we can rewrite this as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{i-1} 1\right) \right).
$$

Comment: Thank you. That was easier than I thought. I seriously don't know what I was doing back there.

Answer (score 0):

In programming, the indices of loops start anywhere you want. I give you below an example for Fortran (sorry for using this language)

SUM=0
DO I = 2 , N
   DO J = 1 , N
      DO K = 1 , I - 1
         SUM = SUM + 1
      ENDDO
   ENDDO
ENDDO